# Spring: How to change default massage in basic auth prompt window?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I use `Spring Security` (version `3.0.5.RELEASE`). Here is my XML config settings:

```
<security:http>
    <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```

Spring provides me a message when I try to get access to the system:

```
A username and password are being requested by http://localhost:8080. The site says "Spring Security Application"
```

I want to change a message `Spring Security Application` to another one. I tried to use a handler:

```
<security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
```

My Java bean:

```
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, AccessDeniedException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resp.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"My authenticate\"");
    }
}
```

But it does not work. How can I change the message?

*UPD*

The problem in the header. It contains next ket-value: `WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring Security Application"`. Even if I set auto-config `<security:http auto-config="true">` my code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute for that:

```xml
<security:http realm="My authenticate">
  <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```